# Why are screentime allowed websites not permitted for access?

Tags: ipad, safari, safari-extensions, screen-time

On my son's iPad I have screentime enabled with downtime scheduled and two categories to control:

1. All apps (except three in one category) time limit 45 min
2. A test category with the microsoft.com website allowed 23 hours a day

[image: Screentime settings with the two categories mentioned]

However when I navigate to microsoft.com on safari it is blocked "**you have reached your time limit on microsoft.com**". I've tried adding [www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com) and just microsoft.com (though I expect both to work and enable access?)

Why is this not working as expected? Are there any viable alternatives to control website access, vs the mess that is Apple Screentime? I'd like to do this in a browser level, simply whitelist a series of sites.

Comment: As a test, can you add a domain not commonly used by companies to continually have their apps check into or used for advertising (google, Facebook, etc.)  Try a shopping site like `macys.com` or `hm.com` just as a test.  Give it a short time limit like an hour or two and see if the exception works as expected.

Comment: Thaks for the suggestion, but that also doesn't work... still blocked.

Comment: This might be a bug.  I'd definitely recommend leaving feedback at https://www.apple.com/feedback/ipad/. And...just to completely verify...leave the block on and check tomorrow to see if it resets.  It shouldn't have to, but it's good to get some diagnostic info.

Comment: Maybe you are hitting a limit in the 45 minute one? Hold the iPad for the night then try in the morning.

Comment: It is still blocked the next morning. I also wondered if the 45 min limit was being hit -  though safari and the sites are not included in that category - and this is the start of the day. I also tried to disable the other category and it's still blocked. 

Screentime is so dysfunctional I will consider buying another iPad for 'school work' and one for games.  Apple wins in the end I $uppose.

Comment: It now allows unlimited access to sites not in the whitest. Screentime is not fit for purpose.